# AutoCompleteTextView - An exception occured during performFiltering()!

Tags: android

I'm having some issues building a AutoCompleteTextView.

I'm trying to show some Json Data inside a AutoCompleteTextView but is not working.

I'm receiving those errors when I try to write something:

```
W/Filter(13081): An exception occured during performFiltering()!

W/Filter(13081): java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:93)

W/Filter(13081): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.performFiltering(ArrayAdapter.java:457)

W/Filter(13081): at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
```

Here, my Json Data

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","name":"Aveiro"},{"id":"2","name":"Beja"},{"id":"3","name":"Braga"}]}
```

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<String> responseList;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       AutoCompleteTextView auto1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

       new HttpGetTask().execute();

   } 

   private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

       String URL = "http://192.168.1.70/example/suggestion.php?name=";
       AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
           HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
           ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
           try {
               return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
           } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
               exception.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException exception) {
               exception.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           try {
               JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
               Log.v("ResponseCity", result);

               List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();

               for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                  final JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
                   String name = e.getString("name");
                   responseList.add(name);
                }

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           if (null != mClient)
               mClient.close();


       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
               android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, responseList);
              AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
               findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

       textView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that a `JSONException` is thrown leaving `responseList` uninitialized. The JSONException is because of this line

```
 JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
```

The api call is returning a `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`. To fix the `NPE`, move  `List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<String>();` before the `try` block. This way, if you don't change anything else, you will provide an empty dataset. The app will not crash (at least with the same stacktrace)